# OpenOCD with XDS200 JTAG Emulator

Tags: openocd, jtag

So I have a Blackhawk XDS200 Debug Probe (TMDSEMU200-U) and I would like to use OpenOCD to debug on my target platform (IWR6483).

When I create a config file, I get the error:

```
Error: Can't find interface/xds200.cfg
```

The config file is:

```
source [find interface/xds200.cfg]
adapter speed 5500
transport select jtag
source [find target/ti_cc13x2.cfg]
```

Is there a reason it can't find this specific config file? When I change it to xds110.cfg, it doesn't give me this error (provided I connect the debug probe).

Alternatively, could anyone point me to this specific xds200.cfg file I could download?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

XDS200 isn't one of the debug interfaces in https://github.com/openocd-org/openocd/tree/master/tcl/interface, so I don't think it is supported yet. I am also interested in OpenOCD supporting this debug probe!

Comment: I opened a discussion with OpenOCD's official ticket system: https://sourceforge.net/p/openocd/tickets/364/